# Ошибка при отправке почты в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, sendmail, email

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема с отправкой почты с сайта (обратная связь).

Перенесла сайт на хостинг (hostinger), бесплатный аккаунт - это может быть важно, так как они там недавно отключали какой-то компонент почты для бесплатных аккаунтов, но вроде как не полностью.

В режиме разработки при отправке ошибок не возникало.
Поменяла параметр useFileTransport на false и при отправке теперь вылезает эта дичь:

> escapeshellcmd() has been disabled for security reasons

Точно не понимаю, что это значит. То ли надо сменить метод отправки как-то в самом фреймворке, то ли проблема в хостинге..

Как можно это исправить, вдруг кто сталкивался?
Или придется обращаться в поддержку хостинга?

Answer (score 1):

Ну так тут четко написано что метод escapeshellcmd() отключен на сервере, если вы имеете доступ к серверу то в php.ini файле включите эту опцию, если вы используете бесплатный хостинг то такой возможности скорее всего у вас нет и вам ее не включат, так как она не секьюрная. Вывод один :) купите дешевый хостинг :)

Comment: Спасибо, буду искать)

Answer (score 0):

Такая же проблема и такой же хостинг(бесплатная версия) только я не использую фреймворка. А просто оправляю через функцию mail.Функция возвращает тру но письмо не приходит.Также смотрел настройки почты вроде бы SMTP включен но все же мне кажется что можно использовать обратную связь в платной версии.